# Environment to hide number from numbered equations

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'd like to create an environment that hides equation numbers from numbered equations. I'd should work like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% ---------------------------
% \begin{nonumber}
\begin{equation}
a + b = c \quad \text{this equation should be unnumbered}
\end{equation}
% \end{nonumber}

\begin{equation}
a + b = c \quad \text{this equation should be numbered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why not simply use `equation*` ? (amsmath, or `\[`)

Comment: To make a long story short, I'm inputting them from an external text file which I load with a command, so the intended use would be like `\begin{nonumber}\thatcommand\end{nonumber}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only using `equation`s, then the following will suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{noeqnumber}
  {\renewenvironment{equation}{\[}{\]}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{noeqnumber}
  \begin{equation}
    a + b = c \quad \mbox{this equation should be unnumbered}
  \end{equation}
\end{noeqnumber}

\begin{equation}
  a + b = c \quad \mbox{this equation should be numbered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\nonumber` already exists, so you'd have to use a different environment name, like `noeqnumber`.

---

If you're using `align`s, then we can adjust the counter stepping and tag printing mechanism:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
% New tag form that gobbles the number
\newtagform{gobble}[\@gobble]{}{}
\makeatother

\let\oldrefstepcounter\refstepcounter

\newenvironment{noeqnumber}
  {\renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{%
     % Only step counter if it is not equation
     \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{##1}{equation}=0\else
       \oldrefstepcounter{##1}%
     \fi
   }%
   \usetagform{gobble}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{noeqnumber}
  \begin{align}
    a + b &= c     \quad \text{this equation should be unnumbered} \\
        d &= e + f \quad \text{this equation should be unnumbered}
  \end{align}
\end{noeqnumber}

\begin{equation}
  a + b = c \quad \text{this equation should be numbered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```